# how to get Eval value to string in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I need to receive data from Eval function to make comparisons, so i've tried this but can't receive anything from Eval, or Bind.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <%
      string auc_id = ((string)Eval("Item_BelongToAuction"));
      Guid id = Guid.Empty;
      Guid.TryParse(auc_id, out id);
      try
      {
          using (ModeloEntities modelo = new ModeloEntities())
          {
              var auction_name = (from auctions in modelo.Auctions
                                  where auctions.Auction_ID == id
                                  select auctions).First();
              Response.Write(auction_name.Auction_Name);
          }
      }
      catch { }
      %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your logic to the code behind, like this:

```
protected string GetAuctionName(string auctionId) 
{
    Guid id = Guid.Empty;
    Guid.TryParse(auctionId, out id);

    using (ModeloEntities modelo = new ModeloEntities())
    {
        var auction_name = (from auctions in modelo.Auctions
                              where auctions.Auction_ID == id
                              select auctions).First();
        return auction_name.Auction_Name;
    }
}

<ItemTemplate>
    <%# GetAuctionName((string)Eval("Item_BelongToAuction") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Note that `Eval` is used inside `<%# %>`, not `<% %>`.